# Time/frequency color map in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-frequency

Is there in native Python 3.X library or in scipy/numpy/matplolib libraries a function or their short set which could help me to draw a plot similar to this one(?):

[image]

What would be an efficient way to achieve something like this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I guess you can easily create this kind of plot using `gridspec` to arrange the subplots and plotting a line plot and a heatmap. However at the moment your question is way to broad for a good answer.

Comment: Have you seen matplotlib's `specgram`? (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram)

Comment: @cel, I'm not interested in the upper plot, but the lower one - the heatmap, as you called it. I wonder, how can I plot this type of map for a 1D signal.

Comment: Well have a look at @WarrenWeckesser's comment then.

Comment: @cel matplolibs' specgram function does not work well, and I can't achieve results similar to those shown above with it. But thank you for suggestion.

Comment: perhaps you could post the (MATLAB?) code used to produce your example image. Then we might find a good Python equivalent. Right now its hard to judge why `specgram` would not suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom plot is the result of Continuous Wavelet Transform.  There is a function called cwt() in Scipy.
Check it out here. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html